# Saving the output of find to a variable in a remote server

Tags: ssh, rsync, variable, remote, sshpass

```
# Declare the array
declare -a LC_lines

# Read the lines of the file into the array
readarray -t LC_lines < unique_running_jobs_directory.log



sshpass -p password ssh -n dummy@dummydomain.xx.yy.zz "

cd /home/dummy/Desktop
files=(${LC_lines[@]})
existing_paths=()

for ((i=0; i<=\${#files[@]}; i++)); do
         result=$(find . -type d -name "\${files[\$i]}")
         cd $result
         cd ..
         rsync -ravuh --progress dummy@dummydomain.xx.yy.zz:/remote_location ./
done
```

I am having trouble with the script. The `result` variable is empty. If I do not save the output of `find`, then the location of the directory is printed out properly. If I save it to a variable and do an `echo` on that variable, it shows an empty string, and I cannot `cd` into it to perform the `rsync`. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trying, I figured out that even when saving to a variable I should use an escape character for every variable. The updated code looks like this

```
# Declare the array
declare -a LC_lines

# Read the lines of the file into the array
readarray -t LC_lines < unique_running_jobs_directory.log



sshpass -p password ssh -n dummy@dummydomain.xx.yy.zz "

cd /home/dummy/Desktop
files=(${LC_lines[@]})
existing_paths=()

for ((i=0; i<=\${#files[@]}; i++)); do
         result=\"\$(find . -type d -name "\${files[\$i]}" -print)\"
         cd \"\${result}\"
         cd ..
         rsync -ravuh --progress dummy@dummydomain.xx.yy.zz:/remote_location ./
done
```